# Can't find a bug in my code

Tags: java

I am trying to finish my assignment but I can't seem to find the bug in my code. It is not a compiler error, and I have been looking at it for hours.

This code is for a game called Mastermind. These are the guidelines (a bit long, I know, but all necessary info for the assignment):

> 1. Computer chooses a random 4 digit number, and no digit may repeat itself. (ex: 0462, 2930, 6103 are valid numbers)
> 2. The user's goal is to try and guess the computer's chosen number
> 3. Once the user makes a guess, the computer will tell the user how class that guess was by giving the following information:
>      The number of digits matched perfectly (are in the right place)
>       The number of digits that are off place
>
> When you scan the input from the user, use a String to store it. Your
>   program **must** have 4 methods in addition to the main method:
>
> - One method named isValidNumber that checks if a given String corresponds to a valid 4 digit number.
> - One method named perfectMatches that returns the number of perfect matches between two Strings that represent valid 4 digit numbers.
> - One method named offPlaceMatches that returns the number of ‘off place’ matches between two Strings that represent valid 4 digit
>     numbers.
> - One method named generateRandomValidNumber that returns a String that represents a random valid 4 digit number.
>
> Hint: Generate a random 4 digit number by generating a random single
>   digit 4 times and concatenating them. Then using your isValidNumber
>   method, check if this String you created is valid. If it is not,
>   repeat the first part and pick 4 new random digits.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //print welcome, what 4 digit number do you guess...
        System.out.println("Welcome to Mastermind.");
        System.out.println("I have a 4 digit number in mind. Can you guess it?");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("What is your guess?");
        //string guess is number that is scanned
        String guess = input.nextLine();
        String validNumber = generateValidNumber();
        System.out.print("Perfect matches: " + perfectMatches(guess, validNumber));
        System.out.println("off place: " + offPlaceMatches(guess, validNumber));

        while(!(perfectMatches(guess, validNumber) == 4)) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("What is your guess?");
            guess = input.nextLine();
            validNumber = generateValidNumber();
            System.out.print("Perfect matches: " + perfectMatches(guess, validNumber));
            System.out.println("off place: " + offPlaceMatches(guess, validNumber));
        }

        System.out.println("Yes! You guessed my number correctly. Well done.");

    }

    static boolean isValidNumber(String number) {
        if(number.length() != 4) {
            return false; }
        char[] numberArray = new char[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            numberArray[i] = number.charAt(i);
            if(!((number.charAt(i) <= '9') && (number.charAt(i) >= '0'))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            char c = numberArray[i];
            int count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                if(numberArray[j] == c)
                    count++;
            if(count > 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    static int perfectMatches(String one, String two) {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < one.length(); i++) {
            if(one.charAt(i) == two.charAt(i)) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }

    static int offPlaceMatches(String one, String two) {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if(i == 0)
                    continue;
                if(one.charAt(j) == two.charAt(i)) {
                    counter++;
                }
                if(j == i -1) {
                    i++;
                }
            }

        }
        return counter;
    }

    static String generateValidNumber() {
        boolean validNumber = false;
        String newNumber = "";
        while(!validNumber) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                char c = (char) (int) (Math.random() * (9));
                newNumber = newNumber + c;
            }
            if(isValidNumber(newNumber))
                validNumber = true;
        }
        return newNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: What indication do you have that there is a bug?

Comment: What are you expecting and what is happening? And also learn to use debugger.

Comment: As a first step to debugging any program that uses random numbers, use java.util.Random with a way to force the seed, so that you can do multiple runs with the same sequence of random numbers.

Comment: When I run the code, it prompts me to enter a number, I do, and nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem in the `generateValidNumber` method.

You are not re-initializing `newNumber` when you try to find a new random number.

Changing it to the following function should result in the successful execution of the program. Also, multiply the random number with 10 to get an number in the range [0.0, 10.0) (0 included and 10 excluded)

```
static String generateValidNumber() {
    boolean validNumber = false;
    String newNumber = null;
    while(!validNumber) {
        // add this line
        newNumber = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            char c = (char) ('0' + (Math.random() * 10));
            newNumber = newNumber + c;
        }
        if(isValidNumber(newNumber))
            validNumber = true;
    }
    return newNumber;
}
```

But there are a few logical errors in the code. For e.g., you are generating a new number everytime a user guesses an invalid number.

Update:
I made a few changes to your code. This should help you get going.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MastremindString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // print welcome, what 4 digit number do you guess...
        System.out.println("Welcome to Mastermind.");
        System.out
                .println("I have a 4 digit number in mind. Can you guess it?");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("What is your guess?");
        // string guess is number that is scanned
        String guess = input.nextLine();
        String validNumber = generateValidNumber();
        System.out.print("Perfect matches: "
                + perfectMatches(guess, validNumber));
        System.out.println("off place: " + offPlaceMatches(guess, validNumber));

        while (!(perfectMatches(guess, validNumber) == 4)) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("What is your guess?");
            guess = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Perfect matches: "
                    + perfectMatches(guess, validNumber));
            System.out.println("off place: "
                    + offPlaceMatches(guess, validNumber));
        }

        System.out.println("Yes! You guessed my number correctly. Well done.");

    }

    static boolean isValidNumber(String number) {
        if (number.length() != 4) {
            return false;
        }
        char[] numberArray = new char[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            numberArray[i] = number.charAt(i);
            if (!((number.charAt(i) <= '9') && (number.charAt(i) >= '0'))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            char c = numberArray[i];
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                if (numberArray[j] == c)
                    count++;
            if (count > 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    static int perfectMatches(String one, String two) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < one.length(); i++) {
            if (one.charAt(i) == two.charAt(i)) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }

    static int offPlaceMatches(String one, String two) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < one.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < two.length(); j++) {
                if (one.charAt(j) == two.charAt(i) && i != j) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }

    static String generateValidNumber() {
        boolean validNumber = false;
        String newNumber = "";
        while (!validNumber) {
            newNumber = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                char c = (char) ('0' + (Math.random() * 10));
                newNumber = newNumber + c;
            }
            if (isValidNumber(newNumber))
                validNumber = true;
        }
        return newNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the line, but it still isn't executing properly.
And yeah, @abiessu pointed out the logical error, I'm currently fixing that.

Comment: Ohh! I'm sorry, I overlooked the char conversion. Try this function as in the answer.

Comment: I updated the `offPlaceMatches` method. Also removed the extra call that generated new random numbers each time. Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, thank you so much for the help! What a great community

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are generating a new number on every cycle.  The best way to fix this is to not assign to the `validNumber` variable within `main(...)` on every loop.

Since you get to the point of "What is your guess?" and you enter a number, but then nothing happens (which presumably means you do not get past the two lines following the first `guess=input.nextLine();` call), the function to check first is the `generateValidNumber();` function.  Second, check your `perfectMatches(...);` function.  You can add `System.out.println("blah");` calls to see how far your code gets (as a very crude debugging tool).

Comment: How exactly will `static` help?

Comment: It really shouldn't be the first approach, but presumably there is no valid number on the first call, so one needs to be generated, but then the `boolean validNumber=false;` could be declared `static` along with the `newNumber` value in which case if `validNumber` is true upon entering the function then `newNumber` could be returned immediately.

Comment: @PM77-1: actually, it probably isn't the best approach to make that function have `static` variables; I'll remove that part of my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Eclipse and in an introductory programming course. An important subject often overlooked in programming courses is how to use a debugger to help you troubleshoot problems. If any of your classmates, lab assistants, or fellow students further along in your major can take 15-30 minutes to sit down and show you how to use the debugger, it will help you through the rest of your programming career.

If not, there are a lot of tutorials you can follow to get familiar with Eclipse's debugger.

To start off, double-click along the left of your code, usually just left of the line numbers. This will add a break point, which will pause your program when it reaches. Add a break point at each of your methods besides `main` and make sure that all the methods you think should be called are actually called.

When your program is at a break point, you can also take a look at the value of variables in the "Variables" view. If one of them has an unexpected value, you may have found your culprit.

There is a resume button you'll have to hit to resume program execution when you're done at a given break point. It should be next to the Pause and Stop buttons in the top bar by default, and is easy to confuse with the Run button.

Comment: I am using intelliJ IDEA and yes, our professor has not gone into depth for debugging

Comment: I'm not familiar with intellij IDEA, but it looks like its debugger is similar to Eclipse's debugger. First tutorial video on Google looks like a decent intro: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7W9kDgHP2k

Answer (score 0):

First: You never call isValidNumber to check if the user's input is valid. You should call this method and if the number is invalid, the program should terminate or prompt the user for a new number

Comment: Technically, I don't believe this is necessary, given how the `perfectMatches(...)` function operates.  If other comparison techniques were used then this would be absolutely necessary...

Comment: I believe it is necessary in this case or it would not be part of 
user3366456's assignment. I would assume not using the method at all would count against user3366456 during grading.

Comment: The method is used, but only in the `generateValidNumber` function.

Comment: Then, when comparing with the internally-known number, a character-by-character comparison is used; if the user enters non-numeric characters the comparison simply logs a failed match and continues.

Comment: Then I guess we'll have to disagree on that point.  Implementation-wise, this particular mechanism will work as needed.  Unless the OP will enforce failure to input any characters except numbers at the entry line (which is probably very far from desirable in such a program), then the user should be allowed to input whatever and the program can gracefully handle it.  This particular implementation is one such way of gracefully handling invalid input.

Comment: The program should not call perfectMatches() unless the user inputs a valid number. Methods should be as simple as possible. Checking to see if the number is valid and checking to see if the number is a perfect match are two separate functions and should be represented as such. Otherwise, the program checks anything for a perfect match. If the user enters a word, the program checks to see if it is a perfect match. This is a flaw in design. Also, the isValidNumber should be used to check the user's input not just the generated number.

Comment: Hmm...  So are you the person who assigned this task to this student?  Why did you delete your other copy of this comment and post it again?  You say "Methods should be as simple as possible."  Note that it is simpler to check whether each character results in a match than to check whether there is valid input and then check whether each character results in a match.  Also, your repeat post resulted in some repetition in your statements.